# getting mail from same email SMTP asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I am working on sending contact information to admin when user fills contact form. Almost everything is working fine but, I am receiving mail from the same address. 

`protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                mail.To.Add("admin@gmail.com");
                mail.From = new MailAddress(EmailTextBox.Text, "Head", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                mail.Subject = "Query";
                mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                mail.Body = "Contact Details" + "<br/> <b>Name:</b>" + Request["app-name"] + " <br/> <b>Email - Address :</b>" + EmailTextBox.Text + "<br/> <b>Description :</b>" + Request["AppointmentMessage"] + "<br/> <b>Contact Number :</b>" + Request["app-num"];
                mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin@gmail.com", "admin");
                client.Port = 587;
                client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                try
                {
                    client.Send(mail);
                    Page.RegisterStartupScript("UserMsg", "<script>alert('Successfully Send...')</script>");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Exception ex2 = ex;
                    string errorMessage = string.Empty;
                    while (ex2 != null)
                    {
                        errorMessage += ex2.ToString();
                        ex2 = ex2.InnerException;
                    }
                    Page.RegisterStartupScript("UserMsg", "<script>alert('Sending Failed...');if(alert){ window.location='SendMail.aspx';}</script>");
                }
            }
        }`

Here, the admin email id is admin@gmail.com. When an user named **user@gmail.com** fills up contact form. When he submits that form, the admin is not receiving mail from the **user@gmail.com**. Instead he gets mail from **admin@gmail.com**

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**If this is possible I can send emails as you without knowing your gmail credentials!**

You are connecting to gmail smtp server from admin credentials, gmail will allow only to send email `from field` as admin or admin attached emails which already configured. It doesn't matter what you set as from address, gmail will over-write it for prevent spamming..

if you need to keep user in the email thread, you can use **To** or **CC** properties